# Ghostscript PDF printing garbled

Tags: pdf, printing, cmd, ghostscript, postscript

I'm trying to use Ghostscript 9.02 on Windows 7 to print a PDF to an Epson Workforce printer from the command line using the following command:

```
   gswin32c -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies=1 -sDEVICE=epson -sOutputFile=\\spool\EPSON C:\Document1.pdf
```

When executing this command, pages will print from my printer, but it is just garbled text instead of the PDF.

[image]

I have tried 3 different PDF files with similar results.

Comment: Try other ghostscript -sDEVICEs with epson in them. My installation has 'epsonc', too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that the previous answer is the issue, but rather is a problem with getting the epson format data passed through correctly as binary. Particularly if the 'init_string' == "\f\033@" doesn't make it in,
the rest of the data will be interpreted by the printer as text instead of raster data.

Since you are on Windows, you may get better results by using the -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 device which sends the raster image for the page through GDI to the manufacturer's driver. See http://artifex.com/gs-current-release/Devices.htm#Win for documentation on printing from windows using Ghostscript.

BTW, you can easily check if the problem is with gswin32c being able to properly render the input PDF by
looking at it on the default 'display' device using:

```
gswin32c C:\Document1.pdf
```

Comment: This solved the problem! I was using epson as the -sDEVICE because my printer is an Epson, but using mswinpr2 instead worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

your problem may be probably related with encoding used by pdf file

how this pdf has been produced?

I seen several times this problem arise with pdf produced by internal pdf exporter of OpenOffice

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue, and it looks like not all listed devices are capable of printing PDF files. I have used ljet4 option for Ricoh network printer and it prints fine. The only problem is it always prints immediately instead of "HoldPrint" queue.